# Итератор на последний элемент std::deque

Tags: c++

Непонятная ошибка при получении итератора на последний элемент очереди. Вот такой просто код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>


int main
{
    std::deque<int>my_deque;

    my_deque.push_back(1);
    my_deque.push_back(2);

    std::deque<int>::iterator my_iter = my_deque.end();   //Ошибка: cannot dereference out of range deque iterator

    std::cout << *my_iter;    
}
```

> cannot dereference out of range deque iterator

> невозможно разыменовать итератор deque вне диапазона

Но почему ? Что нет так ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `end` возвращает итератор, который указывает на условный элемент, находящийся за последним, а не на последний. Ошибка возникает не там, где вы указываете, а на следующей строке.

```
std::cout << *my_iter; //этот элемент не существует
```

Чтобы вывести последний элемент, надо уменьшить итератор на единицу:

```
std::cout << *std::prev(my_iter);
```

> А зачем вообще такое нужно ?? Зачем возвращать итератор на несуществующий элемент ?

Есть несколько применений такого итератора.

1. Определение размера контейнера или части контейнера. Размер можно найти простым вычитанием двух итераторов: `size = end - begin;`, либо, если итератор конкретного контейнера не поддерживает операцию вычитания, то с помощью функции `std::distance(begin, end);`.
2. Обход контейнера в цикле. Для обхода обычно пишут такой цикл:

```
for (auto it = container.begin(); it < container.end(); it++) {...}
```

3. Для возврата ошибочного результата в некоторых функциях stl. Например, функция `std::find` возвращает `end`, если искомый элемент в контейнере не найден.

Следует ещё отметить, что есть в stl есть функции поиска, которые возвращают итератор не на найденный элемент, а на тот, который находится сразу за искомым. Таковым может быть и итератор `end`. Например, функция [std::upper_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) ищет в контейнере начиная с некоторого итератора одинаковые элементы, и возвращает итератор, который следует сразу за последним одинаковым элементом<sup>1</sup>. Почему не на последний? См. п. 1. Вот пример использования:

```
const std::vector<int> data = {5, 5, 5, 6 };
auto it = std::upper_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), 5); //ищем итератор на элемент, который находится сразу за пятёркой
size_t fives_count = std::distance(data.begin(), it);
```

<sup>1</sup> Строго говоря, определение этой функции немного не такое: она ищет первый элемент больше заданного. Просто здесь мне кажется, что так легче объяснить.

Comment: конкретно для итератора std::deque можно *--my_iter

Comment: Спасибо, в описании так и написано, пропустил. А зачем вообще такое нужно ?? Зачем возвращать итератор на несуществующий элемент ?

Comment: Так удобнее проходить циклом по контейнеру: `it < my_deque.end();`, а также end возвращается многими алгоритмами stl при ошибочном результате. Например, функция `std::find` возвращает `end`, если не нашла того, что искали.

Comment: Вот ещё одно применение итератора `end`. Чтобы узнать размер контейнера, можно выполнить простое вычитание двух итераторов: `end-begin`, хотя в некоторых случаях, когда оператор вычитания не определен, нужно использовать функцию `std::distance` с теми же итераторами.